# Событие по клику javascript

Tags: javascript

В общем нужно что-то наподобие отправки сообщений на стену как на facebook. Есть поле Input, при клике на него появляется увеличенный input и кнопка отправки комментария. Подскажите в каком направлении копать? Если можно, поподробней.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я предпочёл реализовать Вашу проблему с помощью **`jQuery`**. Делаем следующее: у Вас есть текстовое поле для ввода информации. Кнопку отправки изначально скрываем. Текстовое поле делаем небольшим. При получении фокуса текстовым полем - показываем кнопку отправки и увеличиваем само текстовое поле. В принципе, у Вас это было описано в вопросе, поэтому подробней не могу описать. Теперь посмотрим на код.

Код **HTML**:

`<textarea cols="30" rows="1" name="text" id="text_field"></textarea>
 <input type="submit" />`

Код **jQuery**

`$(function(){
    $(':submit').hide();
    $('#text_field').focus(function(){
        $(':submit').show();
        $(this).attr({
            'cols': '70',
            'rows': '20'});
    });
});`

Чтобы посмотреть, что получилось, надо сходить [по этой ссылке](http://jsfiddle.net/LeD4eG/GX4Gq/)

Comment: а как сделать, чтобы при отсутствии фокуса форма принимала начальный вид?

Comment: для этого нужно использовать другие события: `focusin()` и `focusout()`. первый вариант - для получения фокуса (в нём мы прописываем изменения размера текстового поля), второй - для расфокусировки - в нём прописываем применение изначальных параметров.